# Script# create classes like class1.class2.class3

Tags: javascript, script#

I have construction in JavaScript like

```
Class1 = {
  Class2: {
    Class3: {
      someFunc: function(){
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I write this code similar on Script# ?
Because code like this

```
public static class Class1 {
  public static class Class2 {
    public static class Class3 {
      public static someFunc(){
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Did not compile.

Comment: That first block isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Its just example, but not working code

Comment: Does my answer answer your question, @АндрейЖиряков?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the return type in your C# function declaration:

```c#
public static someFunc(){
```

Should be:

```c#
public static int someFunc(){
```